# Extract data from element <form action = "..."> for GTM

Tags: javascript

Please tell me how i can extract data with help JS or jQuery in Google Tag Manager (add Custom JavaScript Variable) to get the value of an element in the form action attribute.

For example, I have several forms on the site and they have different actions:

```
<form action = "call2 / 5" method = "post" class = "bp">
<form action = "order2 / 5" method = "post">
<form action = "order / 5" method = "post">
<form action = "order / 5" method = "post">
<form action = "order / 5" method = "post">
<form action = "call" method = "post">
<form action = "feedback" method = "post">
```

I need to get: call2 / 5, order2 / 5, order / 5, etc. I want to write the value separately to a variable.

The Custom JavaScript variable needs to follow two simple rules. First, the script must be wrapped in an anonymous function block (function() { ... }). Second, the function must have a return statement (return somevalue;).

Thanks!

Result: call2 / 5, order2 / 5, order / 5

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a particular `<form>` element based on its `action` value, use this:

```
function getFormByAction(action) {
    return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("form")).find(form => form.action === action);
}
```

or, an ES5 version:

```
function getFormByAction(action) {
    var allForms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var i = 0; i < allForms.length; ++i) {
        var form = allForms[i];
        if (form.action === action) {
            return form;
        }
    }
}
```

This will return `undefined` if no form with the specified action exists.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But these forms do not have identifiers and classes, but there are differences in action name

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov How would you like to identify a particular form then? Do you need to retrieve a form given its action name? (for instance, do you want to find the form whose action is `order2 / 5`?)

Comment: That is why the question arose) That is, the simplest is to specify a unique identifier for each form and already extract data based on it?

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov I've edited the answer and added a function that allows you to find a `<form>` by its action; please see if this solves your issue.

Comment: I tried last code, but it gave an error:

Error in line 3 (symbol 67): This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function.

Comment: @YakovOsipenkov That means you only have ES5 available, which is an older version of JavaScript with fewer features. I've updated the answer with ES5 code as well, see if that works for you.

Comment: Validated, but not defined (((

My site: [link](http://graphanalytics.ru)

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `form`s in the document and get their actions with a $.each

```
var result = "";
$("form").each(function(_, v){
    result += ", " + $(v).attr("action");
});
result = result.replace(", ", "");
return result;
```

Edit: switched `trimStart` with `replace`

Comment: I wrote such code:


    function () {
    var result = "";
    $("form").each((_, v) => result+=", " + $(v).attr("action"));
    result = result.replace(", ", "");
    return result;
    }


And the GTM compiler gave me an error: Error in line 4 (symbol 16): This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function.

Comment: I have updated the code to not use arrow functions anymore. Can you retry now?